# How to show proper html output in mail sent using php mail() function?

Tags: php, ajax, email, html-table

I have a forgot password form.

I am taking email ID to send mail.

HTML code:

```
<form action="#" method="post">
     <table border="0" width="" id="forgot_password">
         <tr>
             <td>Enter Email ID:</td>
             <td><input type="email" name="email_id" id="email_id"/></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td colspan="2"><span class="message validation"></span></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
             <td></td>
             <td><input type="button" name="forgot" class="myButton" value="Submit"/></td>
         </tr>
     </table>
</form>
```

On Click of forgot button i am calling ajax function as:

```
jQuery(function($) {
        var val_holder;

        $("form input[name='forgot']").click(function() {
            var email = jQuery.trim($("form input[name='email_id']").val());
            var email_regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$/;

            if(email == "") {
                alert("Please Enter Email ID");
                return false;
            }
            if(email != "") {
                if(!email_regex.test(email)){ // if invalid email
                    $("span.message").html("Your email id is invalid.");
                }
            }

            $("span.validation").html("");

            var datastring = 'email='+ email;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST", // type
                url: "forgot_password_details.php", // request file the 'check_email.php'
                data: datastring, // post the data
                success: function(responseText) 
                {   // get the response
                    if(responseText == 1) { // if the response is 1
                        $("span.message").html("<img width='15' height='15' src='image/delete_agent.png'> Email id doesn't exists.");
                    }
                    else{
                        $("span.message").html("<img width='15' height='15' src='image/correct.png'> Sent mail to you.");
                    }
                } // end success
            });
        });
    });
```

in `forgot_password_details.php` i am checking whether mail is exists or not.

If mail is exist in database then sending mail to that email id:

forgot_password_details.php

```
<?php
   $uemail = $_POST['email'];

    $user_emailid = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE email_id = '$uemail'");

    if(mysql_num_rows($user_emailid) == 1){
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($user_emailid);

        $email_id = $row['email_id'];
        $username = $row['uname'];
        $password = $row['upassword'];

        $to      = $email_id;
        $subject = 'login credentials';
        $message = "<html>
                        <body>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Login credentials:</td>
                                    <td></td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Username:</td>
                                    <td>$username</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Password</td>
                                    <td>$password</td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </body>
                    </html>";

                    //echo $message; die;

        $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "From: Fairmacs";
        mail($to, $subject, $message, $header);
    }
    else{
        echo '1';
    }
?>
```

I am getting the mail but html is printing as it is in a mail.

So how to print it in user readable form as we show in browser.

Please help me out to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: some thing might problem in ytour headers

Comment: @KarthickKumarGanesh: I tried with iso-8859-1 in header but i was not able to show html output in proper format. I also tried with UTF-8 but result was same.

Comment: What mail client are you using?  And what configuration?  Some clients are explicitly set not to render html.

Comment: @AleksG:Where should I get these settings?

Comment: You, from the server side, do not have any control over it - it's specific to each individual user how they configure their clients. Whether these settings are even available and where/how to access them depends on the client.

Comment: @AleksG:Actually, I'm having another website running on the same server. From that website I'm able to send the mail which displays the HTML in proper user readable form. But it's not the case with my this website. So it's clear that there is no such setting which is preventing HTML rendering. There must be some cause in above code. Can you help me in correcting this issue?

Comment: I don't see anything really wrong with you code.  If you have another site, from which the mail is working fine - just copy the code from that site.

Comment: @AleksG: I have already copy and pasted it but then also it is not displaying properly.

Answer (score 0):

please try below line for $headers

```
$boundary = "nextPart";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "From: Me <youeemail>\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary = $boundary\r\n";
//text version
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n"; // beginning \n added to separate previous content
$headers .= "Content-type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "This is the plain version";
//html version
$headers .= "\n--$boundary\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "This is the <b>HTML</b> version";
```

instead of

```
 $headers = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
 $headers .= 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: I tried with iso-8859-1 in header but i was not able to show html output in proper format. I also tried with UTF-8 but result was same.

Comment: charset will have no bearing on the output.